# Regex for identifying strings which just has special character and a white spaces

Tags: c#, regex

I trying to find out whether a string just contains | and a white space and nothing else in it using a regex in c#.
I tried the below expression but that does not identify exactly and it gets all the records which are falling out.

```
Regex reg = new Regex("^[^a-zA-Z0-9@#!.]+$");
```

The list of not keeps on extending.
Thanks in advance for any help on this.

Thanks,
VJ

Comment: Your description and your regex don't quite match in meaning. Are you trying to get a match if the string contains only spaces and `|` or are you trying to get a match if the string contains even 1 space or `|`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using the following to directly target what you want to match instead of what you *don't* want to match:

```
new Regex(@"^[\s|]*$");
```

A breakdown:

- `^` - start of string
- `[...]` - any of the following:

  - `\s` - whitespace character
  - `|` - literal |
- `*` repeated any number of times (including 0 times)
- `$` end of string

Comment: Thanks that worked, i tried that expression but not with *. Can I please know what difference does that make.

Comment: Without the `*`, the expression would only match a string consisting of _one_ whitespace character or `|`.